# VSTO - can't create special folders in Outlook 2010 for IMAP account

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have an issue in Outlook 2010 when i try to create special folders (with type Calendar, contacts, tasks) for IMAP account. This issue not reproduced from Outlook 2013 and higher.
Outlook says "Can't crate folder. The IMAP protocol cannot support special folders. Only mail folders may be created."
Why it's only reproduced on Outlook 2010 and early? How solve this issue?

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Sounds like a product issue, not a programming question, right?

Comment: I'm trying to create folders programmatically via the Folders entity, specifying the folder type, and I'm getting an exception with the same message as when I tried to do it manually (see screenshot). This code works correctly for Outlook 2013 and older, but not for Outlook 2010 and earlier versions, I don’t understand what this is connected with.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a new folder with a specific default message class you need to use the [Folders.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folders.add) method and specify the second parameter which stands for the Outlook folder type for the new folder. If the folder type is not specified, the new folder will default to the same type as the folder in which it is created. It can be one of the [OlDefaultFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders) constants. So, if you need to create a calendar subfolder you need to pass the `olFolderCalendar` constant.

Comment: I do it as you described. But it doesn't works for Office 2010 and earlier, only from Office 2013 it's works correct.